# How to create a role that cannot create or alter a table?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role

I want to create a role named manager in postgresql . This role can update, select, delete and insert data in all tables but users that belong to this role cannot create a table nor modify the schema.

I tried the following sql statement:

`CREATE ROLE manager
  NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;`

How can I achieve this condition?.

Answer (score 3):

The privilege to create tables is granted to new roles automatically. You need to [`REVOKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-revoke.html) the role's `CREATE` privilege on the **`schema`** (not the `database`):

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA myschema FROM manager;
```

[Per documentation on `GRANT`:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-grant.html)

> `CREATE`
>
> For databases, allows new schemas to be created within the database.
>
> For schemas, allows new objects to be created within the schema. To rename an existing object, you must own the object and have this
>   privilege for the containing schema.
>
> For tablespaces, allows tables, indexes, and temporary files to be created within the tablespace, and allows databases to be created that
>   have the tablespace as their default tablespace. (Note that revoking
>   this privilege will not alter the placement of existing objects.)

And `REVOKE` all direct privileges any role might have in respective schemas. By default, plain roles only have privileges for the schema `public` and schemas they create themselves.